# Image in PDF generated with PDFBox disappears when file is moved from local machine

Tags: java, image, pdf, pdf-generation, pdfbox

I've been generating PDFs and adding a logo at the top using a JPEG file. The image in the PDF showed up fine on my local machine (OS X). As soon as I sent the file anywhere else though, the image would no longer appear. I'm using java and PDFBox to generate the PDF.

```
PDPageContentStream contentStream = ...;
PDDocument document = ...;
PDImageXObject image = PDImageXObject.createFromFile("image.jpg", document);
contentStream.drawImage(image, 50, 700, 250, 67);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After upgrading from 1.8.11 to 2.0.0, I've managed to resolve the issue by changing the way the image was added to the PDF.

```
PDPageContentStream contentStream = ...;
PDDocument document = ...;
InputStream imageStream = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("image.jpg");
PDImageXObject image = JPEGFactory.createFromStream(document,imageStream);
contentStream.drawImage(image, 50, 700, 250, 67);
```

The key seems to be the use of:

```
JPEGFactory.createFromStream()
```

instead of:

```
PDImageXObject.createFromFile()
```

Comment: PDImageXObject.createFromFile() should work... if not, try create a test case and then create an issue in JIRA, https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX . Btw a common error is not to close the content stream.

Comment: `PDImageXObject.createFromFile()` essentially does a `FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file); PDImageXObject imageXObject = JPEGFactory.createFromStream(doc, fis)`, so using `JPEGFactory.createFromStream()` instead of `PDImageXObject.createFromFile()` is not a general cure. One thing that strikes the eye, though, is that in your answer you retrieve the image from the resources while `PDImageXObject.createFromFile("image.jpg", document)` obviously tries to retrieve it from the current working directory. Do you probably have a broken copy of the image in the current working directory?

Comment: @mkl - It doesn't appear to be an issue with a broken image file location, as the image does show up in the pdf. The problem presents itself when I move the pdf somewhere other than my local machine, for example AWS S3. When the PDF is moved, all of the text and other formatting is still visible, but the image is no longer visible.

Comment: AWS S3... do you mean access to the image via URL?

Comment: @mkl. I don't understand. Here's the situation I ran into originally:

    `1. Create PDF locally
    2. PDF (with image embedded in PDF) looks good!
    3. Upload PDF (with image looking good) to AWS S3
    4. View PDF in AWS S3 or Download PDF
    5. PDF no longer has visible image in it`

Comment: Unless you eventually have a PDF which references the image as external resource, your originally situation sounds like either the upload or the download damaged the file. As you have not provided a sample PDF, I cannot tell.